# How to apply this function to a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, new-operator

Suppose I have this df:

```
i      A     B     C

0     4     5    13
1    11    42    27
2     3     6    2.21
3     4     8    10
4    10     5    4
5     2    11    .5
```

and want to apply a this function to each row:
log[(df['A']

```
$log((A_i - A_{i+1})^2+(B_i - B_{i+1})^2+(C_i - C_{i+1})^2)$
$log((A_i - A_{i+2})^2+(B_i - B_{i+2})^2+(C_i - C_{i+2})^2)$
.
.
.
$log((A_i - A_{i+5})^2+(B_i - B_{i+5})^2+(C_i - C_{i+5})^2)$
```

For example for i=0 and i=1:

```
$log((4 - 11)^2+(5 - 42)^2+(13 - 27)^2)=3.2$
```

I have this code. But is not working.

```
for point in df:
    x = [np.log((A[0]-A[1] )**2+ (B[0]-B[1] )**2+(C[0]-C[1] )**2) for x in df]
```

Answer (score 1):

Difference the rows forward via `df[['A', 'B', 'C']].diff(-1)`, square the result via `.apply(lambda x: x * x)` (or `.pow(2)`), sum the result via `.sum(axis=1)` and then take the log of these sums.  Assign the result back to the dataframe.

```
>>> df.assign(result=np.log(df[['A', 'B', 'C']].diff(-1).apply(lambda x: x * x).sum(axis=1)))
   i   A   B      C    result
0  0   4   5  13.00  7.386471  # np.log((4 - 11) ** 2 + (5 - 42) ** 2 + (13 - 27) ** 2) = 7.386...
1  1  11  42  27.00  7.588093
2  2   3   6   2.21  4.184857
3  3   4   8  10.00  4.394449
4  4  10   5   4.00  4.720729
5  5   2  11   0.50      -inf
```

Alternatively, to difference every row from the first, use `(df[['A', 'B', 'C']].iloc[0, :] - df[['A', 'B', 'C']])`. Everything else is the same.

```
>>> df.assign(
        result=np.log(
            (df[['A', 'B', 'C']].iloc[0, :] - df[['A', 'B', 'C']]).pow(2).sum(axis=1))
    )

   i   A   B      C    result
0  0   4   5  13.00      -inf
1  1  11  42  27.00  7.386471
2  2   3   6   2.21  4.774272
3  3   4   8  10.00  2.890372
4  4  10   5   4.00  4.762174
5  5   2  11   0.50  5.279389
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. How can i make it tha it gives you hte difference between i and j. No just i+1. For example i want it for A_i-A_{i+2}, A_i-A_{i+3},...A_i-A_{i+5}

Comment: Can you please edit your question to reflect the expected result given the sample data?

Comment: Yes. Thank you :)